Can we have $|\overline{X}_n - E[X_1]| > \varepsilon$ infinitely often?
Let's say I have some random variables, $X_1, X_2, ...$ which are identically distributed with finite expected value, $E[X_1]$ and say they satisfy the requirements of the law of large numbers. Let
$$\overline{X}_n = \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n}.$$
The LLNs says $\overline{X}_n \to E[X_1]$ both in probability and a.s. But, my question is this: is it possible that, for some $\varepsilon > 0$, that $|\overline{X}_n - E[X_1]| > \varepsilon$ infinitely often with non-zero probability? Do we need the variance to be infinite for this or can we do it with finite variance? Does it matter if the $X_i$ are independent or not?

What does almost surely mean to you?

@User1865345 yes.... going point. I'm gong to go hide behind a couch and pretend I never asked this question. :)

Independence matters.  Otherwise consider $X_1=X_2=X_3=\cdots$

If a sequence of numbers approaches a finite limit, then, no matter how small the positive number $\varepsilon$ is, only finitely many terms of the sequence are more distant than $\varepsilon$ from the limit.
To say that a sequence of random variables converges almost surely is to say that to "almost every" point in the probability space there is assigned a sequence that is just as in the paragraph above. The measure of the set of points in the probability space at which the sequence satisfies the inequality $\left| \overline X_n - \operatorname E(X_1)\right|>\varepsilon$ for infinitely many values of $n$ is zero.

If the measure of the set of points is zero, does that also mean that it never happens? There are infinitely many rational numbers among the real numbers, but their measure is zero.

@SextusEmpiricus Notice that the question says "with non-zero probability".
